# How to use an ImageMoniker from a .imagemanifest in an ISuggestedAction

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2019

Instead of simply text, I'd like to be able to include a custom icon for each of the actions in my lightbulb actions list so that it is an icon and text (see below).

[image]

I've included the .imagemanifest in the VSIX, as well as the png. Below is what my foo.imagemanifest looks like as well as a snippet from my `ISuggestedAction` implementation. 
First off, is this even possible? If so, is there any thing else that has to be done to see the image in the lightbulb action? Does it have to be somehow registered with the image catalog/service, or possibly using `IVsImageService2.GetImageMonikerForFile(String)`?

my `foo.imagemanifest`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This file was generated by the ManifestFromResources tool.-->
<!-- Version: 14.0.50929.2 -->
<ImageManifest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/ImageManifestSchema/2014">
  <Symbols>
    <String Name="Resources" Value="/MyCompany.VisualStudio;Component/Resources/Lightbulb" />
    <Guid Name="MonikersGuid" Value="{2a63e4c2-d4a6-5d82-aeb2-84935e052cd3}" />
    <ID Name="bug" Value="0" />
  </Symbols>
  <Images>
    <Image Guid="$(MonikersGuid)" ID="$(bug)">
      <Source Uri="$(Resources)/bug.png">
        <Size Value="16" />
      </Source>
    </Image>
  </Images>
  <ImageLists />
</ImageManifest>
```

`ISuggestedAction` implementation contains:

```
public ImageMoniker IconMoniker => 
new ImageMoniker {Guid = new Guid("2a63e4c2-d4a6-5d82-aeb2-84935e052cd3"), Id = 0};
```

Comment: Hi brianc, it seems you want to provide your own icon in vsix. And you want to replace the yellow suggestion lightbulb if anyone installs the extension?

Comment: hi @LanceLi-MSFT, I'm not looking to change the lightbulb icon specifically, I want to add custom icons (.png files) to the actions inside the lightbulb menu

Comment: According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-displaying-light-bulb-suggestions?view=vs-2019), it seems to not support icons in extension. But I'm not certainly sure about it, so i'm trying to confirm this point with an engineer who's experienced in this topic. Maybe it takes some time:)

Comment: that would be kind of a bummer, since there is a `IconMoniker` property that has to be implemented...

Comment: But your final purpose is to add custom icon into light bulb menu, where it once only displays text(not sure if i misunderstand your meaning), after my check it seems to be not possible now.

Comment: that's correct, I want to display a custom icon + text for each of my lightbulb actions (i updated my question with more description and a screenshot).

Comment: I understand what you want, but I have no idea how to reach that since I haven't find related api which allows that kind of extension for light bulb. I find the similar function in Resharper, but it doesn't extend light bulb from vs, instead it extends a custom light bulb, maybe you can consider this way.

Answer (score 2):

I also had problems to create custom moniker.
Then I found an example on [VSSDK github repo](https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/Menu_And_Commands/C%23).
The **Menu_And_Commands** Example shows how its working.

There are a few points to consider here:

- The imagemanifest file shall be inside the vsix file.

  - Property: **Include in VSIX = true**

  Make sure that the imagemanifest file is also in the AppData Extension folder if you run your extension in debug mode
  --> C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_1234abcdExp\Extensions\{author}\{product_name}\{version}
- The imagemanifest file shall be placed directly inside your c# project.
  If you put it somewhere inside a project folder it will not work.
- The png file shall be added as resource.

  - Property: **Build Action = Resource**

  Make sure that the image is really inside your dll and the path is correct.
  Rebuild your vsix project if you are not sure.

I don't know if its necessary but for me it only worked if I created an separate VSIX project with an VSIX package for the imagemanifest file. If this VSIX package is installed then Visual Studio will know the GUID of the moniker and other VSIX packeges will find it.

This imagemanifest file worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageManifest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
               xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/ImageManifestSchema/2014">
    <Symbols>
        <String Name="Resources" Value="/MY.ASSEMBLY.NAME;Component/Resources" />
        <Guid Name="guidMyMoniker" Value="{08EF3AF1-7D26-4652-8923-6593CFE5392B}" />
        <ID Name="idImage1" Value="1" />
        <ID Name="idImage2" Value="2" />
    </Symbols>
    <Images>
        <Image Guid="$(guidMyMoniker)" ID="$(idImage1)">
            <Source Uri="$(Resources)/16x16/Image1_16pxl.png">
                <Size Value="16" />
            </Source>
            <Source Uri="$(Resources)/32x32/Image1_32pxl.png">
                <Size Value="32" />
            </Source>
        </Image>
        <Image Guid="$(guidMyMoniker)" ID="$(idImage2)">
            <Source Uri="$(Resources)/16x16/Image2_16pxl.png">
                <Size Value="16" />
            </Source>
            <Source Uri="$(Resources)/32x32/Image2_32pxl.png">
                <Size Value="32" />
            </Source>
        </Image>
    </Images>
    <ImageLists />
</ImageManifest>
```